# Choregraphe 2.5.5: More than 20 outputs on Dialog Box

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I'm using Choregraphe 2.5.5 to program Pepper. I have one topic with lots of outputs (over 20) which Chroregraphe doesn't like. So, I used two dialog boxes with the same topic (made in Choregraphe 2.1.4). Now on my virtual robot, it basically only runs on of the dialog boxes, not both (which is what I want and what happened in Choregraphe 2.1.4).
Is there anything I can do to have more than 20 outputs on a topic with a dialog box?
Thanks.

Comment: Given the complexity of your logic I would recommend that you script everything rather than using box output.  It sounds like you can solve your problems by using memory events.
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/almemory-tuto.html

Can you give some more detail?

Comment: @Anders_K So I also asked one of my teachers and he said to just output a string in my topic script and then use a switch case to do my outputs and to make the switch case take a string from my topic script as an input. Would that be a possibility? I’ve only just began programming the Aldebaran robots using Choregraphe around 3 months ago in school. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, outputting a string and switching would totally be possible too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 20 outputs to your box is indeed a sign that your project will be complicated and hard to maintain ... do you *really* need all those outputs?

Some possibilities:

- Split this into several dialogue topics
- Make outputs that are strings or numbers instead of being empty, containing a code indicating what to do, and have a switch (as you suggest in a comment). This makes sense if some outputs are, for example "finishSUccessfully", "finishFailure"; or ""goToStep1", "goToStep2", etc.
- Do more logic in Python, less in dialogue

... the specifics are really going to depend on your app and why you need so many outputs.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. How would I send strings via an output of a dialog box? Would I just do something like: $output=“doThisAction”

Comment: Yep, though I expect in practice something more like $finishedOutput=success, or $pickedLevel=3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Also in Dialog when you write $myValue=1234 then "myValue" doesn't have to be an output but can also be an event. The good thing with events is that you can connect them separately (use the big + on the left hand side of choregraphe to add an output for your event), so your project can get cleaner maybe?